# How can I insert data between the data with my inputs in python / json?

Tags: python, json, append

I have inputs `a` and `b`, and I want to insert them into my json file.

```
import json

with open("intents_kor.json") as file:
data = json.load(file)

a = input('input a : ')
b = input('input b : ')

data['intents'].append({'tag': 'not_in_json', 'patterns': ['a'], 'responses': ['b'], 'context_set': ''})
```

I want to put my inputs `a` and `b` to `a` and `b` with `append()`.
How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you want your dictionary to look like before and after adding certain input. Also, please demonstrate what you have tried and where it fails. The more information you provide us, the better we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
import json

with open("intents_kor.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

a = input('input a : ')
b = input('input b : ')

data['intents']={'tag': 'not_in_json', 'patterns': [a], 'responses': [b], 'context_set': ''}
print(data)
```

Comment: The OP has not clarified what the issue is exactly. Or rather what the end result has to look like.

Comment: @marxmacher I understood what is his issue. So I gave the answer.

Comment: I think a little description would be good to have here. Right now this is of little help for others who might come to this issue and want to understand. thanks.

Comment: @Stan was that your intention to overwrite the [a] and [b] everytime? or did you want to append to "patterns:" and "responses": everytime you ran the code? Thanks.

Comment: @VaibhavJadhav Oh, I picked it. :)

Comment: @marxmacher I just wanted to overwrite it into .append() every time I run the code :)